WordPress cURL 400
I have been trying to figure out why I am getting a cURL 400 status and how to fix it in WordPress.
Basically, when a user completes a form on the WordPress page and clicks submit, a bunch of functions get triggered.
I just added the function below.  I tested the API in Postman and it works fine, but it doesn't want to work from this WordPress site.
Using the PHP Inserter from the WordPress dashboard, I have inserted the following code that makes an API call:
function test(){
  $url     = "https://api.ongage.net/MY_LIST_ID/api/transactional/send";
  $xun = "X_USERNAME: " . MY_USERNAME;
  $xpw = "X_PASSWORD: " . MY_PASSWORD;
  $xac = "X_ACCOUNT_CODE: " . MY_ACCOUNTCODE;
  $content = '{
   "list_id": ,
   "campaign_id": ,
   "recipients": ["myEmail@email.com"],
   "check_status": true,
   "sending_connection_id": MY_SENDING_CONNECTION_ID
  }';

  $curl    = curl_init( $url );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-type: application/json",
    $xun,
    $xpw,
    $xac 
  ) );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content );
  $json_response = curl_exec( $curl );
  $status        = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
  
  if ( $status != 200 && $status != 201 ) {
    $error = error_log( "Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, 
      response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error( $curl ) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno( $curl ) );
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("fail "+'.$status.')';
    echo '</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("success")';
    echo '</script>';
}
  curl_close( $curl );
  $response = json_decode( $json_response, true );
}

In the IF statement above, the alert window shows a 400.  I have no idea why, and I am not sure how to to check it.
Edit
I made an adjustment to the $content variable in the code above.  It now looks like this:
  $content = '{
   "list_id": MY_LIST_ID,
   "campaign_id": MY_CAMAPAIGN_ID,
   "recipients": ["myEmail@email.com"],
   "check_status": true,
   "sending_connection_id": MY_SENDING_CONNECTION_ID
  }';

So I added the list_id and campaign_id, and upon submitting the form, I am now receiving a 404 error.
I really think it has something to do with the contents.  I am referencing this page: https://ongage.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/HELP/pages/947486763/Transactional+Mailing+API+Methods

edit your question to show us the http headers and the content of the response.

@mmm - This code is within the WordPress PHP Inserter plugin.  I don't see any headers, just a few other functions.  Some of the other functions are making API calls and are using the same cURL operators, but none of the other functions are using an API to send a transactional message (email).  To my knowledge, the other functions that are using the cURL operators are not having any issues, just mine.

I don't know this plugin, I just speak about your code. change your code to see the http headers and the content of the response.

@mmm I am not sure about the HTTP headers.  I see the CURLOPT_HEADER which is in the code I provided.  Is that not what you are referring to?  If not, I literally do not see any other headers.

You're logging errors to the debug.log file, have you checked it yet? If so, what does it say?

@cabrerahector This site is a stage site that is hosted with a company called Siteground.  I see the error log for the stage site, but there is nothing in there except an apache warning that reads something like "timeout waiting for output from CGI script".  I don't think that's related to my problem.

I found the problem.
In the content variable, I have the below:
$content = '{
 "list_id": MY_LIST_ID,
 "campaign_id": MY_CAMAPAIGN_ID,
 "recipients": ["myEmail@email.com"],
 "check_status": true,
 "sending_connection_id": MY_SENDING_CONNECTION_ID
}';

"list_id" is supposed to be "message_id".  That's what was causing the 404 status.  After making that update, I received a 200 response and the transactional message was sent.
#yay
